# 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to use a neural network, but I have a problem importing Tensorflow. It used to work well a few months ago. I think I've been trying to access my graphics card without having it, or at least without access to it. At the moment, here's the mistake:

```
>>> import tensorflow

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py in preload_check()
     74         try:
---> 75           ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
     76         except OSError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-607-ab280936f4d9> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 
      3 def focal_loss(gamma=2., alpha=4.):
      4 
      5     gamma = float(gamma)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     29 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     30 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     28 # Perform pre-load sanity checks in order to produce a more actionable error
     29 # than we get from an error during SWIG import.
---> 30 self_check.preload_check()
     31 
     32 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py in preload_check()
     80               "environment variable. Download and install CUDA %s from "
     81               "this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive"
---> 82               % (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
     83 
     84       if hasattr(build_info, "cudnn_dll_name") and hasattr(

ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive
```

I'm in the process of uninstalling it to put back a version that fits.

## tensorflow==1.15

There's the same problem and more mistakes:

```
ROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-609-ab280936f4d9>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2034, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1151, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-609-ab280936f4d9>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2034, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3242, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3336, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2037, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1418, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1318, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1186, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2034, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1151, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py in preload_check()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2033                         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.
-> 2034                         stb = value._render_traceback_()
   2035                     except Exception:

AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_code(self, code_obj, result, async_)
   3334             if result is not None:
   3335                 result.error_in_exec = sys.exc_info()[1]
-> 3336             self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
   3337         else:
   3338             outflag = False

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2035                     except Exception:
   2036                         stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(etype,
-> 2037                                             value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
   2038 
   2039                     self._showtraceback(etype, value, stb)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1416             self.tb = tb
   1417         return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1418             self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1419 
   1420 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1316             # Verbose modes need a full traceback
   1317             return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
-> 1318                 self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1319             )
   1320         elif mode == 'Minimal':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1184         exception = self.get_parts_of_chained_exception(evalue)
   1185         if exception:
-> 1186             formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
   1187             etype, evalue, etb = exception
   1188         else:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: Did you use pip or conda to install the module?

Comment: @AaronJones pip, should I have used conda ?

Comment: Maybe you are having issues with modules only existing in certain environments. Try reinstalling it with pip in your IDE, or run a CMD terminal as an admin to install it again.

Comment: @AaronJones Ok, will install `python -m pip install tensorflow==1.15` in jupyter notebook. The error you saw was after installing it in a CMD terminal with admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some instructions: https://www.google.com/amp/s/mc.ai/how-to-install-cuda-10-and-cudnn-for-tensorflow-gpu-on-windows-10/amp/
Just download the dll, extract it to your prefered path and add this path to your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answerr. It's interesting. I don't remember having  doing that the first time I worked with tensorflow